# Pneumatics distribution of elements

Tags: image, text

1. 

Objective:

Application of limit switches Problem:

The double-acting cylinder ejects the elements onto the conveyor belt.  The actuator is started by means of the manual button 53, and it is automatically withdrawn after reaching the front position.

reaching the rear position.

Recommendation:

• Draw a diagram of the pneumatic and electrical system for two cases of actuator control:

1. pulse solenoid valve (two coils) 2. solenoid valve (one coil) Build the circuits on the assembly board

• Start up and check operation

i need the pneumatic and electrical diagram of these two examples preferably for Fluidsim appearance Please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.